# How to incorporate List Functionality in a custom model class

Tags: list, flutter, dart, model

I'm trying to include standard List functionality into an object model, but can't for the life of me work it out.

This is what I'm doing

- Working with EPUB XML files that contain chapters, href links for each chapter etc
- Each chapter and relevant info is pulled into a model / object
- The parsing of XML file to get required info is fine
- Creating a model for the individual elements and assigning parsed info is fine
- However, I can't solve creating a model LIST of the individual elements that allows me to utilise .add .length or access any of the standard list functionality.

So, I could easily go List listOfIndividualItems = [] and then .add

But how do I incorporate this into a model/object scenario where (say) :
BookReference bookReference ; and then bookReference.add ?

Surely I wouldn't need to create .add() methods etc. for my model and can somehow inherit?

The following are my models. Thanks for your help.

---

```
class BookDirectoryItem {
  final String mediaType, href;
  final int order;
  final String idRef;
  BookDirectoryItem(
      {required this.href,
      required this.mediaType,
      required this.idRef,
      required this.order});
}

class BookDirectory {
  final List<BookDirectoryItem> bookDirectoryItems;
  BookDirectory({required this.bookDirectoryItems});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* want your `BookDirectory` to behave identically to a `List<BookDirectoryItem>`, just create a type alias with Dart 2.13's new feature.

To utilize this feature you need to change your minimum sdk constraint in your pubspec.yaml to 2.13:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"
```

Then in your code you can do

```dart
typedef BookDirectory = List<BookDirectoryItem>;
```

Then using `BookDirectory` will be identical to `List<BookDirectoryItem>`.

If you want to add extra functionality, you can do this with extension methods:

```dart
extension Books on BookDirectory {
  BookDirectory mediaTypeSubDirectory(String mediaType) {
    BookDirectory newDir = [];
    for (BookDirectoryItem item in this) {
      if(item.mediaType == mediaType) {
        newDir.add(item);
      }
    }
    return newDir;
  }
}
```

---

If this is for some reason undesirable, you *have to* manually add some of the list functionality to your class, though this is made somewhat easier with the [`ListMixin`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/ListMixin-class.html). You just need to define a few function and the mixin will take care of the rest.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class BookDirectory with ListMixin<BookDirectoryItem> {
  final List<BookDirectoryItem> bookDirectoryItems;
  BookDirectory({required this.bookDirectoryItems});
  
  int get length => bookDirectoryItems.length;
  set length(int v) {
    bookDirectoryItems.length = v;
  }
  BookDirectoryItem operator[](int index) => bookDirectoryItems[index];
  operator[]=(int index, BookDirectoryItem value) {
    bookDirectoryItems[index] = value;
  }
  void add(BookDirectoryItem item) => bookDirectoryItems.add(item);
}
```

Comment: Both of the the above solutions worked excellent. Marked as answered. Thanks heaps.